# SuiteScript Error with Custom Module on OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I've been running into some issues wherein a handful of users running NetSuite installations I have created run into an error when it comes to accessing a custom module I have created. The common thread in each situation is that they are using MacOS/OSX. I haven't gotten anything solid when it comes to the browser, though, so I'm not entirely certain whether it happens regardless because it's a Mac, or if it may be a problem with a specific browser, likely Safari. I don't have access to a computer running MacOS, so I'm not in a good position to try and test, poke around, see what's happening.

The error specifically is:

```
JS_EXCEPTION
TypeError
undefined is not an object (evaluating ModuleName.Attribute)
```

This never happens on any machine running Windows, and I've checked in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Opera. And I've also managed to do a limited amount of testing on Linux (Debian & Ubuntu) with Firefox without issue.

So, for example, I might have a custom module like this:

```
/**
 * CustomModule.js
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NModuleScope Public */
define([],

() => {
    
    const FunctionGroup1 = {
            fg1Action1 : (paramA) => {
                // do something
            }
        ,   fg1Action2 : (paramB, paramC) => {
                // do something
            }
    };
    
    const FunctionGroup2 = {
            fg2Action1 : () => {
                // do something
            }
        ,   fg2Action2 : (paramD, paramE, paramF) => {
                //  do something
            }
    };
    
    return {
            fg1 : FunctionGroup1
        ,   fg2 : FunctionGroup2
    }
    
});
```

And then my client script will essentially be initialized like this:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/runtime', 'N/search', './CustomModule'], function(runtime, search, CM) {
    
    const fieldChanged = (context) => {
        // handle field change event
    };
    
    return {
        fieldChanged
    };
    
});
```

And then the error displays if a line within that "fieldChanged" function calls something like this:

```
let sampleValue = CM.fg1.fg1Action2("valueA", "valueB");
```

In that situation the error would display something like the following:

```
JS_EXCEPTION
TypeError
undefined is not an object (evaluating CM.fg1)
```

Since I don't have any access to a machine running MacOS/OSX, I can't test to see if there's something wrong with my module, or something wrong with how whatever browser is the problem on a Mac processes the way NetSuite loads custom modules into a browser. Anyway, I'm hoping someone has come across this and knows what to do.